# Program in Android to upload .json file & recieve .json response

Tags: android, json, http

I am supposed to develop a program in android which uploads a .json file to a webservice & get back the response in .json format & parse it. Can anybody tell me how to upload a json file & any webservice which takes a .json file,validates it & returns a .json file? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

An ideal setup would be

Android App <-> GAE

If you need the web-service to just check you json file...simply read the json content at the server into a JSON object and if no exception is thrown you are good to go with the response to the client.

I have provided code that uses Restlet (restlet.org) on both sides.

---

**Android App**

---

```
Client client = new Client(Protocol.HTTP);
Request req = new Request();
req.setMethod(Method.POST); // can be Method.GET
req.setResourceRef(new Reference(/* SERVER URL */+ "/jsonservice"));
req.getCookies().add(GAuth.getCookie());
/* Build your JSONObject */
req.setEntity(/* JSONObject */.toString(), MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
req.getClientInfo().getAcceptedMediaTypes().add(new Preference<MediaType>(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
Response resp = client.handle(req);
if (resp.getStatus() == Status.SUCCESS_OK)
{
    // resp.getEntity().getText() -> The JSON string returned by GAE
    JSONObject jo=new JSONObject(resp.getEntity().getText());
    /* Use your JSON object */
}
```

---

**GAE App**

---

> **GAE : war/WEB-INF/web.xml**
>
> ```
> <!-- Servlets -->
> <servlet>
>   <servlet-name>MyApplication</servlet-name>
>   <servlet-class>org.restlet.ext.servlet.ServerServlet</servlet-class>
>   <init-param>
>       <param-name>org.restlet.application</param-name>
>       <param-value>com.mypackage.MyApplication</param-value>
>   </init-param>
> </servlet>
>
> <!-- Servlet Mappings -->
> <servlet-mapping>
>   <servlet-name>MyApplication</servlet-name>
>   <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
> </servlet-mapping>
> ```
>
> ---
>
> **Restlet : MyApplication.java**
>
> ```
> package com.mypackage;
>
> public class MyApplication extends Application
> {
>   @Override
>   public Restlet createInboundRoot()
>   {
>       Router router = new Router(getContext());
>       router.attach("/jsonservice", MyJsonService.class);
>       return router;
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> ---
>
> **Restlet : MyRouter.java**
>
> ```
> package com.mypackage;
>
> public class MyJsonService extends ServerResource
> {
>   @Post("json:json") // can be @Get("json")
>   public Representation jsonProcessor(Representation entity)
>   {
>       Representation resp = null;
>       JSONObject req = (new JsonRepresentation(entity)).getJsonObject();
>       /* 
>           Do Someting with the JSON object
>           .....
>           .....
>           .....
>           Build your JSON response object. 
>           You will use this object below.
>       */
>       setStatus(Status.SUCCESS_OK);
>       resp = new JsonRepresentation(/* JSONObject */.toString());
>       return resp;
>   }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Uploading json file is not different from uploading any other file type. There is an example  [here](http://getablogger.blogspot.com/2008/01/android-how-to-post-file-to-php-server.html). It explains how to upload a file to php server.

<strike>And http://json.org/ has a java library you can use to create/parse the json objects.</strike> As the comment below points, there is a json library included in android.

Comment: Actually, android has a JSON library included. See [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/package-summary.html).